# Is it me or are DynamoDb Streams just really lacking?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have an application running in multiple regions in AWS, this application reads from global DynamoDb table(s). Updates occur in the background via another process and I wanted to be able to be able to monitor for these updates so the application can invalidate its cache (I'm not using DAX).

I was thinking I could use DynamoDb streams for this, however; after going through a number of road blocks with Spring Kinesis Streams Binder (e.g. the fact that it requires 2 tables [*SpringIntegrationMetadataStore* & *SpringIntegrationLockRegistry*] be created, my company doesn't allow dynamic creation of tables (so that was fun to hunt down as I couldn't find any mention in the docs - ‍♀️ maybe I missed it). Now I think I have found out that only [1 application can listen to a Kinesis stream at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378232/spring-cloud-stream-kinesis-binder)?

*Is that true?*

**Is there a way**

Is there a way for multiple applications, that only read from DynamoDb, to get notified when an update occurs? I was thinking that I could use DynamoDb Streams such that each app would monitor the stream for updates and be able to invalidate their cache. If the above is true, then I need to do something more involved or complex (use a SNS/SQS for updates, elasticache, Redis, Kafka) which just seems like overkill for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> e.g. the fact that it requires 2 tables [SpringIntegrationMetadataStore & SpringIntegrationLockRegistry]

Well, that's how consumer group management is handled by Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder. Even if you would use only a KCL, it still would require from you extra table in DynamoDB. Therefore your concern sounds more like a lack of confidence in cloud services you use.

> Now I think I have found out that only 1 application can listen to a Kinesis stream at a time?

That's not true if all your consumer applications are configured for different consumer groups.

Please, make yourself familiar with Spring Cloud Stream and its model: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_main_concepts

Another way probably could be done via AWS Lambda trigger for DynamoDB Streams: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So my main "issue" with the tables (whether its 2 for Binder or the 1 for KCL) was that I didn't really see any mention of it in the docs. So it took me a while to figure out that was why it wasn't working. As I mentioned my company doesn't allow dynamic table creation, so it has to be created before hand via Terraform.
Interesting, so if each app instance has its own group then it can listen to the update? Thanks for that Link, I'll take a look at it!

Comment: Not sure what you mean about docs. It is here indeed: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#metadatastore

Comment: I appreciate your help and don't want to debate documentation quality, in hindsight the info is 'there'.
With your pointers I've got working code now. 